# How to make dendograms more visual?

Tags: r, data-mining

I have a baseball data set that I'm running Hierarchical clustering algorithm on.

```
CluBattingAL <- battingAL[,c("G","R","H","HR","OBP","ERP", "AB", "salary")]
disCluBattAL <- dist(CluBattingAL) # find distance matrix
HCluBattingAL <- hclust(disCluBattAL) # apply hirarchical clustering 
plot(HCluBattingAL) # plot the dendrogram
HCluBattingAL
```

After running the above code I get a huge dendrogram that I can't read.

[image]

so, my question is how can I make it more readable ? Maybe something like zooming in or even sampling.

Comment: Have you tried the `ggdendro` package to plot dendrograms ?  There is a very good [vignette on how to use it, here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggdendro/vignettes/ggdendro.html). And some more [examples here](https://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/1876_df0bf890dd54461f98719b461d987c3d.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a general problem with to many groups. You can try to plot it to a huge png file and zoom in using an graphical program.

```
png(filename = "dendo.png", width = 30000, height = 10000)
plot(HCluBattingAL)
dev.off()
```

Often this helps.